# How do I avoid the stream from closing abruptly while I am reading the records from an upstream OData Service while using GetAllRequestBuilder?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am trying to read about 3.9 million records from an upstream odata service using `GetAllRequestBuilder`. The code sets the pageSize to 5000 and uses the instance of `HttpDestination` to read from the upstream service.

The exact snippet that is executed :

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->{
// initial setup code for destination 

Stream<Product> stream = new DefaultProductService()
.getAllProduct()
.withPreferredPageSize(5000)
            .streamingEntities()
            .execute(sourceDestination);

    // ...
    stream.peek(entry -> {log.info("entry: " + entry.toString());})
    .forEach(entry -> publishOnEventBus(entry));

     });
```

After a while, I receive an `ODATADeserializationException`. I cannot share the exact stack trace, but in the stack trace I see `Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed`.
The exception is thrown in the class `HttpEntityReader`.

```
"com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.exception.ODataDeserializationException: A problem occurred while streaming the OData response.","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.request.HttpEntityReader.lambda$stream$0(HttpEntityReader.java:121)"
```

This occurs abruptly, during multiple runs, sometimes 66k records are read, sometimes 400k, sometimes 14k.

**Note :** We use `com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel` to generate the service classes. We use `getAllProduct` that returns a `GetAllRequestBuilder`. The execute method itself returns deserialized entities.

Is there something that I can do to ensure that this exception does not occur and stream continues reading to the end? We are using `sap-cloud-sdk` version `3.48.0`.

Comment: Seems like the HTTP response is already consumed and something tries to parse it again. Can you please share the code how you run the OData request and how you evaluate the response? Are you running `disableBufferingHttpResponse()` on the request? If yes, for investigation purpose, have you tried it without disabling the buffer?
---
"This occurs abruptly, during multiple runs [non-deterministically]"

This makes me assume, you have an asynchronous operation running. Are you trying to parse the response in parallel to something else? Are you accessing the response twice in parallel?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderDümont, we are not running `disableBufferingHttpResponse()`. We generate the service classes from the `edmx` file and use the generated instance of  `getAllRequestBuilder`. After that, we are running the above mentioned snippet asynchronously in a future via the api` `CompletableFuture.runAsync`. The code snippet above itself from cloud sdk internally deserialises the data to the appropriate format generated by parsing the `edmx`.  We are consuming this parsed objects.

Comment: The error does not occur on requesting the data but when trying to read the response. For some reason the `HttpEntity` is already consumed. Can you please outline in your question how you evaluate the `Stream` response? I would expect the evaluation happens inside the `CompletableFuture.runAsync` invocation.

Comment: I added additional details. The code to deserialize the stream is in the cloud sdk. It hands over the individual constructed objects back as a stream and this is the stream that is being processed later in our application code. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to reproduce the issue. When looking into the Cloud SDK code the symptoms may only happen if the Java runtime closes the `InputStream` spontaneously (unlikely) **or** if multiple actors access the `Stream` simultaneously and therefore try to consume the HTTP response in parallel. But this would also be rather strange use-case. Hence my suspicion towards `runAsync`. Now I wonder how you implemented the "subscribers" to the `Stream`. This is why I was asking for code samples.

Comment: Ah ok - the stream is basically chained by two calls, `peek` and `forEach`. The peek prints the entry with `toString` and `forEach` publishes it on event bus. No multiple subscribers

Comment: I've ran a unit-test with over 10 million entities iterated via paginated `Stream#peek#forEach` - without encountering the issue. However I did notice the memory consumption went up quickly. Best case; my mocked server is caching data - worst case; there's a memory leak somewhere. Therefore next question: **Did you check memory consumption?** Maybe your application runs out of resources and stops the processing(?)